# Getting `Cannot access a closed file` when asynchronously copying files

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

I want to copy multiple files asynchronously but i am getting this error,

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed file.
```

Here is my method,

```
public Task CopyAllAsync(IList<ProductsImage> productsImage)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (var productImage in productsImage)
    {
        var task = _fileService.CopyAsync(productImage.ExistingFileName, productImage.NewFileName);
        tasks.Add(task);
    }
    return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

here is the FileService.CopyAsync method,

```
public Task CopyAsync(string sourcePath, string destinationPath)
{
    using (var source = File.Open(sourcePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (var destination = File.Create(destinationPath))
        {
            return source.CopyToAsync(destination);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I am awaiting this,

```
await _imageService.CopyAllAsync(productsImage);
```

If I debug then I will not get this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to `await` the copy operation instead of simply returning the task. That would make sure you're not ending the using scope too soon which means calling `Dispose` on your `FileStream`s

```
public async Task CopyAsync(string sourcePath, string destinationPath)
{
    using (var source = File.Open(sourcePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (var destination = File.Create(destinationPath))
        {
            await source.CopyToAsync(destination);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But this will not make the copying parallel possible. Correct?

Comment: @user960567 It's irrelevant. `CopyAsync` still returns a task and `CopyAllAsync` still `await`s all of theses tasks together.

Comment: I know but I want to copy all files parellely

Comment: @user960567 This doesn't stop you from doing that.

Comment: If I await then the next copy will not executed until the first one finish.

Comment: @user960567 That would be true if you would await `_fileService.CopyAsync` inside `CopyAllAsync`, not if you await `source.CopyToAsync`.

Comment: Are you sure that adding the above code will copy files concurrently. Means if I have `productsImage.Count=3` all files will be copied concurrently.

Comment: @user960567 It would be just as concurrent as it was before.

Comment: I am marking this as answer. But I don't think it will be concurrent. await means the next line of the method will be only execute when async operation completed.